# Image losing quality and size in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an app which takes photos of receipts and upload it to a remote server.

I get the full-sized photo of the image from the camera intent correctly.I followed this using the official documentation in Google developer.

I then set my picture like this.

```
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = imageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    //Bitmap bitmap = null;
    //try
    //{
        //bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver() , //Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
    //}
    //catch (Exception e)
    //{
        //handle exception
    //}
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    new ImageSaver(getApplicationContext()).
            setFileName("currentImage.png").
            setDirectoryName("Android_Upload").
            save(bitmap);


    Model.currentImage = "currentImage.png";
}
```

This works fine when viewed on the device. But after its sent to the server and viewed from there, the image size is too small.

ImageSaver class pretty much saves the image elsewhere and compresses it but with 100 quality in png.I do this, so I can later the image in the database as Blob(again with 100 quality)

How can I decode the image and show the image in the image view but without losing quality (and the size?)

Comment: Do you want to save the full-size photo?

Comment: @Audi Yeah i want the full sized photo. The image i currently have is a full sized photo. But to avoid memory leaks i used the set pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you have scaled down your image while decoding.

You may want to remove the following line:

```
bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
```